# Calculated value displays as hash marks (####) in Access query

Tags: ms-access

I need to determine the GST amount from the retail price. I originally had the retail price plus GST (retail price * 1.1) however i the GST is included in the retail price so i need to use (retail price / 1.1)

```
SELECT Groups.GroupID, Groups.GroupName, Groups.CountryOfOrigin, CDs.CDName,                   
CDs.YearOfRelease, CDs.CDType, CDs.RetailPrice,
([CDs]![RetailPrice]*1.1) AS GST_Inc
FROM Groups INNER JOIN CDs ON Groups.GroupID = CDs.GroupID
WHERE (((Groups.CountryOfOrigin)="australia") AND ((CDs.CDType)="album"))
ORDER BY Groups.GroupName, CDs.CDName;
```

When i change it to divide for example,

```
SELECT Groups.GroupID, Groups.GroupName, Groups.CountryOfOrigin, CDs.CDName, 
CDs.YearOfRelease, CDs.CDType, CDs.RetailPrice, ([CDs]![RetailPrice]/1.1) AS GST
FROM Groups INNER JOIN CDs ON Groups.GroupID = CDs.GroupID
WHERE (((Groups.CountryOfOrigin)="australia") AND ((CDs.CDType)="album"))
ORDER BY Groups.GroupName, CDs.CDName;
```

It does not return any value just hashtags in the field.

When Using ROUND(GST,1) for example,

```
SELECT Groups.GroupID, Groups.GroupName, Groups.CountryOfOrigin, CDs.CDName,
CDs.YearOfRelease, CDs.CDType, CDs.RetailPrice, ROUND (GST,1), [CDs]![RetailPrice]-    
[RetailPrice]  /1.1 AS GST
FROM Groups INNER JOIN CDs ON Groups.GroupID = CDs.GroupID
WHERE (((Groups.CountryOfOrigin)="australia") AND ((CDs.CDType)="album"))
ORDER BY Groups.GroupName, CDs.CDName;
```

I get two returns one as GST which is the one with like 10 decimal points, and a new field EXPR1007 with the rounded GST. How do i make the rounded GST the entry for the GST field? I have tried moving the round statement however it will not accept it.

Comment: Have you tried `Round([CDs]![RetailPrice]-[RetailPrice] / 1.1, 1) AS GST` ...?

Comment: It wont accept that either comes up with syntax error add 'round etc' however that just puts the entire statement into the field due to using '      '

Comment: `SELECT CDs.CDName, Round(CDs.RetailPrice - CDs.RetailPrice / 1.1, 2) AS GST FROM CDs` works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Datasheet View, Access will display hash marks (`#`) if numeric or date values are wider than the column will display.

[image: example1.png]

Just drag the right side of the column to make it wider and the numbers should appear.

[image: example2.png]

Comment: DOH!! Thanks Guys, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hash tags are a sign that the column width is too narrow to show the entire value, so rather than truncate and possibly mislead you, access shows hashes. Either make the column wider, which will show you the number possibly with lots of decimal places, or, because you're dealing with money (and only need two decimal places, wrap the division part in a `Round()` function (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp for more information).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone searching this all these years later, there is an option to handle this. I'm not sure how long the option has been there but it is available now, and makes Access behave more like Excel (fits as many decimal digits as will fit in the column and rounds as needed).

Under File | Options | Current Database | Check for truncated number fields, UNcheck the option for this truncate/round behavior.

[image]